# how to toggle password

Tags: javascript, ruby

In view I have the following ruby code:

```
Password: <input type="password" value= <%= @user_credentials.first.encrypted_password %> id="myInput">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">  Show Password
```

And in js file `app/assest/js` I have the below function,
but toggle password can't be done while checking the checkbox.

```
function myFunction () {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `value` attribute code.

The following snippet works ok.

So js and html code is ok.

Just format the dynamic ruby part correctly.

I guess it should have quotes (for a valid html):

```
value="<%= @user_credentials.first.encrypted_password %>"
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
  if (x.type === "password") {
     x.type = "text";
  } else {
     x.type = "password";
  }
}
```

```html
Password: <input type="password" value="123" id="myInput">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">  Show Password
```

Comment: thnks alot. 
 yes!  i was doing that HTML format  mistake

Comment: may be voting require at least 15 reputation and i"m new sorry to say right now i can't do that

Answer (score 2):

Browsers automatically put quotes if any user forgot to put it. It is the behavior of the browser. So, if you put any space after any attribute, browser will automatically put quotes around that and it will ignore everything which comes after that space. Which can mess your element's markup code.

There should not be a space after any attribute in the markup.

```
value= <%= @user_credentials.first.encrypted_password %>
```

You can fix it by wrapping them in quotes:

```
value="<%= @user_credentials.first.encrypted_password %>"
```